# mxmlc (flex4 beta)command line on ubuntu hangs

Tags: flash, mxmlc

Im using mxmlc to compile as3 on ubuntu linux. I've donwloaded flex4_b2_100509, just to use the most recent stuff...
so Im typing 'mxmlc file.as' but it just hangs on me... it doesnt return anything. I checked running processes ('ps -e') and its showing both mxmlc and java as running, which tells me the compiler started...     after a while the shell reports a 'segmentation fault'

any ideas on what it might be?
thanks

Comment: I have just tried the same thing with flex3.4 and its also hanging... so it cant be the fact the flex4 is a beta...

Comment: also its an Ubuntu 8.04 server

Comment: http://mathing.scroggles.com/wordpress-mu/2008/10/24/mxmlc-segfault-ubuntu-804/

same issue, and its resolution. testing this out right now

Answer (score 0):

http://mathing.scroggles.com/wordpress-mu/2008/10/24/mxmlc-segfault-ubuntu-804/

this resolves the issue